# C#: IEnumerable<T> для Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, многопоточность, foreach, ienumerable

Есть собственный класс **MyNumber**
Необходимо: создать диапазон объектов класса **MyNumber** для обработки его в *Parallel.ForEach*

Сначала как по мануалу создал отдельный класс **MyNumbers**:

```
internal class MyNumbers : IEnumerator<MyNumber>, IEnumerable<MyNumber>
{
    private MyNumber min, max, current;
    public object Current { get => current; }

    MyNumber IEnumerator<MyNumber>.Current => current;

    public MyNumbers(MyNumber a, MyNumber b)
    {
        min = (MyNumber)a.Clone();
        max = (MyNumber)b.Clone();
        current = (MyNumber)a.Clone();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        bool can = current < max;
        if (can)
            current++;
        return can;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        current = (MyNumber)min.Clone();
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyNumber> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

В обычном **foreach** (не многопоточном) работает нормально, в **Parallel.ForEach** выходит всякая чушь (в частности часть элементов диапазона проглатывается, а часть дублируется[особенно элемент, следующий за последним])

Далее нагуглил более простой способ - добавить в основной класс **MyNumber** итератор примерно следующего вида:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyNumber> Range(MyNumber start, MyNumber stop)
    {
        do
            yield return start++;
        while (start != stop);
    }
```

Эффект как от вышеописанного отдельного класса, только гораздо проще и короче. Еще нюанс: при проверке в обычном **foreach** выяснилось, что перебираются элементы не со *start* до *stop*, а с *start+1* до *stop+1*. Эта проблема была решена следующим образом (почему? так и не понял до конца... кто знает - поясните):

```
public static IEnumerable<MyNumber> Range(MyNumber start, MyNumber stop)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return start;
            start++;
        }
        while (start < stop);
    }
```

Далее был опробован вариант, основанный на предположении об одновременных попытках доступа к итератору (хотя я считал, что **Parallel** должен сам как-то исключать такой вариант развития событий):

```
public static IEnumerable<MyNumber> Range(MyNumber start, MyNumber stop)
    {
        object rangeLock = new object();
        do
            lock (rangeLock)
            {
                yield return start;
                start++;
            }
        while (start < stop);
    }
```

Это принесло свои плоды - начальная часть обработки диапазона прям такая как надо... но начиная примерно с <кол-во ядер процессора> элемента опять идет чехарда, только более упорядоченная. Пример: *abceegg*; вместо *abcdefg*
Также появилась плавающая проблема в виде "System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Для не синхронизированного блока кода вызван метод синхронизации объектов." - появляется через раз, т.е. как повезет - либо не те элементы в наборе обработаны, либо exception.

Помогите пожалуйста кто чем может. Заранее спасибо.

**UPDATE:**
Для большей ясности поясню суть класса **MyNumber**: это 62-ричная система счисления, реализованная в байт-кодах символов.

```
internal class MyNumber : ICloneable
{
    private byte[] data;
    public int Length { get => data.Length;}

    public MyNumber(params byte[] list)
    {
        data = list.Length==0 ? new byte[] { 48 } : list;
    }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get => data[index];
        set => data[index] = value;
    }

    public static MyNumber operator ++(MyNumber a)
    {
        int i = a.Length;
        do
        {
            i--;
            a[i] = (byte)(a[i] == 122 ? 48 : (a[i] == 90 ? 97 : (a[i] == 57 ? 65 : a[i] + 1)));
        } while (a[i]==48 && i>0);

        if (a[0]==48)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[a.Length + 1];
            Array.Copy(a, 0, b, 1, a.Length);
            b[0] = 49;
            return b;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static bool operator <(MyNumber a, MyNumber b)
    {
        if (a.Length == b.Length)
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                if (a[i] == b[i])
                    continue;
                else
                    return a[i] < b[i];
        return a.Length < b.Length;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyNumber> Range(MyNumber start, MyNumber stop)
    {
        object rangeLock = new object();
        do
            lock (rangeLock)
            {
                yield return start;
                start++;
            }
        while (start < stop);
    }
}
```

Остальные части класса вроде бы не имеют отношения к заданному вопросу.

Comment: *"перебираются элементы не со start до stop"* если подставить `int`, то перебирается от start по stop-1 (Как и написано). Тут возможно что-то с реализацией вашей `MyNumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно организовали код в `operator ++`
[(Источник догадки и кода)](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/41099/Overloading-increment-operator)

Упрощенно, у вас подобная реализация

```
public class MyNumber
{
    public int IntValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public static MyNumber operator ++(MyNumber instance)
{
    // Неправильно
    instance.IntValue++;
    return instance;
}
```

Таким образом из итератора возвращается всегда один и тот же объект. Но не успевает он дойти до вывода, как его инкрементирует другой поток.

Возможно, подойдёт такая реализация

```
public static MyNumber operator ++(MyNumber instance)
{
    // Правильно, возвращаем новый объект
    MyNumber result = new MyNumber();
    result.IntValue = instance.IntValue + 1;
    return result;
}
```

---

Как видно из обновления вопроса, я был прав --- в большинстве случаев вы возвращаете тот же объект в операторе инкремента.
Не вдаваясь сильно в ваш код, изменения нужно сделать примерно такие

```
public static MyNumber operator ++(MyNumber a)
{
    MyNumber c = new MyNumber(); //Создаём новый объект
    c.data = a.data; //Копируем содержимое, исходного объекта
    //Далее работаем только с новым объектом
    //И возвращаем его, в общем случае
    int i = c.Length;
    do
    {
        i--;
        c[i] = (byte)(c[i] == 122 ? 48 : (c[i] == 90 ? 97 : (c[i] == 57 ? 65 : c[i] + 1)));
    } while (c[i]==48 && i>0);

    if (c[0]==48)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[c.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(c, 0, b, 1, c.Length);
        b[0] = 49;
        return b;
    }
    return c;
}
```

А блокировку в `Range` нужно будет просто убрать.

Comment: Заменил `return a;` на `return (MyNumber)a.Clone();` в операторе ++; убрал блокировку в итераторе. Результат: exception`а конечно нет, но пропуск и повторение элементов в наборе по прежнему наблюдается =(

Comment: @FrankCowperwood Ну то что вы сделали, это же не совсем то, что я вам написал. Вы же когда вызываете `return (MyNumber)a.Clone();` то `a` уже изменили?!

Comment: Да, действительно, поторопился не обдумав. Создание копии входящего объекта в начале инкремента, а не в конце, дало совершенно другой эффект. Пока все работает как надо =)